# hide Create and Edit buttons depend with condition and role odoo 11

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo-11

I would like to hide "Create" and "Edit" buttons on state and group role in form view .For example hide Create and Edit buttons when the state is not draft and user belongs to request user group.

As I understand hide buttons I can on editing views. And on group role rules I can disable create or edit.

I tried to write a rule for request user group but then user can't use the button but see it.

From view I found only way to hide default Create and Edit buttons:

```
<form string="Employees" create="false" edit="false">
```

But in that way I hide them for all users for all states. Is there another way how can I hide Create and Edit buttons depend on state and group role?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For group it is possible you have a form view for all make a new form inherit the old form make create and edit false for this form view and gave group to this form view. Now gave group to user whom you want to make create and edit false. Now point is that it makes two form view one for all and second for specific user whom you want to make it hide or you may do vice versa. Old group user will get create and edit true and user with this group will see this hide in it. Thanx